# how to create a Jquery Mobile button without corners from an input element?

Tags: button, jquery-mobile, rounded-corners

I'm building controlgroups out of Jquery Mobile inputs like so:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup">
    <span class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-bar-a ui-corner-top"><span class="ui-divider-text">Divider</span></span>
    <input type="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" value="text" />
    ....
</div>
```

While this works nicely, I'm often ending up with the input elements also getting corners. I tried overriding JQM by adding *data-corners="false"* to the input

```
<input type="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-corners="false" data-iconpos="right" value="text" />
```

but since this goes on the div.ui-btn wrapping the input element, it doesn't work.

**Question:**
Is there a way to tell JQM to not put corner on an element? I can't add classes to the input element (like **ui-corner-I-don't-need**, because corners will be on wrappring **ui-btn** and **ui-btn-inner**, which I can only access by Jquery (don't want).

Any other ideas?

Thanks for inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with your code just give id to div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#buttongp > div.ui-controlgroup-controls > div:first').removeClass("ui-corner-top");
        });
    </script>


<div data-role="controlgroup" data-inset="true" id="buttongp">
                <span  id="buttonspangp" data-role="list-divider" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-bar-a ui-corner-top"><span class="ui-divider-text">Divider</span></span>
                <input type="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-corners="false" data-iconpos="right" value="text" />
                <input type="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-corners="false" data-iconpos="right" value="text" />
                <input type="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-corners="false" data-iconpos="right" value="text" />
            </div>
```

Comment: that would work. Hate to add extra jquery for stuff like that though.

Comment: ya but you have choosed controlgroup with div and input type. instead of this use ul,li with list view and anchor tag for link. it has already demo on jquery mobile site